# Python abstractmethod with asynccontextmanager

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio, mypy

I have a couple rate limiter classes (one not shown) that I'd like to create an ABC for. The `request` method is an async context manager. With the code shown below I get

> Signature of "request" incompatible with supertype "RateLimiterInterface"

If I try to decorate the abstract method with `@asynccontextmanager`, I get a typing error:

> Argument 1 to "asynccontextmanager" has incompatible type "Callable[[RateLimiterInterface], Coroutine[Any, Any, AsyncIterator[Any]]]"; expected "Callable[..., AsyncIterator[]]"

How can I do this?

```python
class RateLimiterInterface(abc.ABC):
    @abc.abstractmethod
    async def request(self) -> AsyncIterator:
        pass

class LeakyBucketRateLimiter(RateLimiterInterface):
    def __init__(self, max_tokens: Optional[int] = None, rate: float = 60) -> None:
        self.max_tokens = max_tokens
        self.rate = rate
        self._bucket = max_tokens
        self._last_added_at = time.time()

    @contextlib.asynccontextmanager
    async def request(self) -> AsyncIterator:
        if self._bucket is None:
            yield
            return
        while not self._bucket:
            await asyncio.sleep(0)
            self._add_tokens(int((time.time() - self._last_added_at) * self.rate))
        self._bucket -= 1
        yield
        return

    def _add_tokens(self, num_tokens: int) -> None:
        if num_tokens == 0:
            return
        self._bucket += num_tokens
        if self._bucket > self.max_tokens:
            self._bucket = self.max_tokens
        self._last_added_at = time.time()
```

Comment: Have you tried using the `contextlib.asynccontextmanager` decorator in your ABC?

Comment: Yeah, I did try to add `@contextlib.asynccontextmanager` as a second decorator to the abstract request method in my ABC. That's when I get the typing error that I mentioned above.

Comment: please see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/68911014/4088675. Essentially, you need to remove the "async" keyword from the abstractmethod declaration

Answer (score 6):

I just met same problem with typing and solved it that way:

```
import abc
import contextlib
import asyncio


class TestAbstract(metaclass=abc.ABCMeta):
    @contextlib.asynccontextmanager
    @abc.abstractmethod
    # Here the trick: you must declare an  asynchronous generator function,
    # not a regular coroutine function so it have to explicitly yield.
    async def foo(self):
        yield


class SubTest(TestAbstract):
    @contextlib.asynccontextmanager
    async def foo(self):
        yield


async def test_coro():
    async with SubTest().foo():
        print('OK')


asyncio.run(test_coro())
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce problem. Code below runs fine for me (Python 3.7.1).

Please, test if it runs fine in your environment and if it is alter question to provide minimal reproducible example.

```
import asyncio
import abc
import contextlib
from typing import AsyncIterator


class Test(abc.ABC):
    @abc.abstractmethod
    async def request(self) -> AsyncIterator:
        pass


class SubTest(Test):
    @contextlib.asynccontextmanager
    async def request(self) -> AsyncIterator:
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        yield 1
        await asyncio.sleep(1)


async def main():
    obj = SubTest()
    async with obj.request() as res:
        print(res)


asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: Thanks, Mikhail. That does run. I guess I'm just getting errors from mypy.