# How to correctly specify type hints with AsyncGenerator and AsyncContextManager

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy

Consider the following code

```
import contextlib
import abc
import asyncio

from typing import AsyncContextManager, AsyncGenerator, AsyncIterator


class Base:

    @abc.abstractmethod
    async def subscribe(self) -> AsyncContextManager[AsyncGenerator[int, None]]:
        pass

class Impl1(Base):

    @contextlib.asynccontextmanager
    async def subscribe(self) ->  AsyncIterator[ AsyncGenerator[int, None] ]: <-- mypy error here

        async def _generator():
            for i in range(5):
                await asyncio.sleep(1)
                yield i
                    
        yield _generator()
```

For `Impl1.subscribe` mypy gives the error

```
Signature of "subscribe" incompatible with supertype "Base"
```

What is the correct way to specify type hints in the above case? Or is mypy wrong here?

Comment: As a workaround you could make `def _generator()` abstract and implement `subscribe` in `Base' by calling `_generator()`. Then in `Impl1` implement `def _generator()`.

Comment: you don't even need to put `_generator` in `Base`, you could just have a private `_subscribe` in `Impl1` without the decorator (which has the contents of your current `subscribe`) then return `contextlib.asynccontextmanager(self._subcribe())` from the actual `subscribe`. I suspect the problem is that mypy doesn't like you changing the type signature with the decorator, which seems odd since it's a stdlib decorator

Comment: @Wombatz I simplified the code. In my code the `yield generator()` is guarded in try except with subclass specific init and clean-up code. So that would not work.

Comment: @joel True, I remember reading that mypy should, in principle, work with the async contextmanager. But it could be a bug, or maybe I made a mistake.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I just happened to come up with the same problem and found this question on the very same day, but also figured out the answer quickly.

You need to remove `async` from the abstract method.

To explain why, I'll simplify the case to a simple async iterator:

```py
@abc.abstractmethod
async def foo(self) -> AsyncIterator[int]:
    pass

async def v1(self) -> AsyncIterator[int]:
    yield 0

async def v2(self) -> AsyncIterator[int]:
    return v1()
```

If you compare v1 and v2, you'll see that the function signature looks the same, but they actually do very different things. v2 is compatible with the abstract method, v1 is not.

When you add the `async` keyword, mypy infers the return type of the function to be a `Coroutine`. But, if you also put a `yield` in, it then infers the return type to be `AsyncIterator`:

```py
reveal_type(foo)
# -> typing.Coroutine[Any, Any, typing.AsyncIterator[builtins.int]]
reveal_type(v1)
# -> typing.AsyncIterator[builtins.int]
reveal_type(v2)
# -> typing.Coroutine[Any, Any, typing.AsyncIterator[builtins.int]]
```

As you can see, the lack of a `yield` in the abstract method means that this is inferred as a `Coroutine[..., AsyncIterator[int]]`. In other words, a function used like `async for i in await v2():`.

By removing the `async`:

```py
@abc.abstractmethod
def foo(self) -> AsyncIterator[int]:
    pass
reveal_type(foo)
# -> typing.AsyncIterator[builtins.int]
```

We see that the return type is now `AsyncIterator` and is now compatible with v1, rather than v2. In other words, a function used like `async for i in v1():`

You can also see that this is fundamentally the same thing as v1:

```py
def v3(self) -> AsyncIterator[int]:
    return v1()
```

While the syntax is different, both v3 and v1 are functions which will return an `AsyncIterator` when called, which should be obvious given that we are literally returning the result of `v1()`.

Comment: Thank you for sharing this insight. After thinking about your answer it all makes sense now.
So the basic issue is that for an abstract routine mypy cannot infer between generator and normal function (since the `yield` is missing). Or in other words, a `def` or `async def` object has different type, depending on whether `yield` is in its body or not.
I understand that omitting the `async` from the abstract routine solves the problem, but I feel it is more of a workaround than a "correct" solution (which maybe does not exist, due to the mentioned issue).

Comment: `async def` with `yield` in it is actually not a coroutine but an async generator, and vice versa.

Comment: Yes, but also `def` with a `yield` is a generator function and not a normal function. The problem is the legacy design of generator functions. Python infers them from the presence of `yield`, rather than being explicit. This is a design that was avoided with asyncio, where an explicit `async` is needed, rather than inferring from an `await`. If it were explicit, then your abstract method might look like `async gen def` or something similar and the problem would never have occurred.

Comment: So is the following assessment correct? There is no way of distinguishing async generators from async functions returning async iterators by type hinting?

Comment: A function (non-async) which returns an async iterator is the same thing as an async generator (it's essentially syntax sugar). An async function which returns an async iterator is a different thing, reread the above example (`v1()` and `v2()`) and how the abstract method must be changed to match one or the other.